# Special Halacha for first night of Chanuka

Tags: chanuka, riddle

On the first night of Chanuka we make a Sh'echiyanu when we light the candle. What other special Halacha is connected with the first night of Chanuka?

Answer (score 2):

An Avel does not Daven for the Amud the first night of Chanuka. This Halacha is mentioned by the Mishna Berura by Hilchos Rosh HaShana. The reason is since we make a Shechiyahu in Shul that night.

Comment: Nice one. Really couldn't think of it...

Answer (score 0):

An Avel should not be the one lighting the Menora in Shul the first night of Chanuka, as it will bring him to extra Simcha (Nitei Gavriel)